# Find a particular solution of a system of nonhomogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to better understand using the method of underdetermined coefficients to solve a system of DEs. Here's an example of one I'm stuck on at the moment:

> Find a particular solution $x_p(t)$ of this nonhomogeneous systems:
>   $$x' = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 2&-3\end{pmatrix} x + \begin{pmatrix} 5e^{3t} \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$

I think I've arrived at an answer, so hopefully someone can verify if I'm correct:

$$x_p(t) =  \begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}  e^{2t} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Is this right?

Answer (score -1):

We are given:

$$x' = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}5e^{3t}\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

We find:

$$x_h(t) = c_1 e^{-3t} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} + c_2e^t\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \dfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives us:

$$\phi(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & e^t \\
 e^{-3 t} & \frac{e^t}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\phi^{-1}(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{e^{3 t}}{2} & e^{3 t} \\
 \frac{e^{-t}}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

So,

$$\phi^{-1}(t).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 5 \exp (3 t) \\
 3 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 3 e^{3 t}-\frac{5 e^{6 t}}{2} \\
 \frac{5 e^{2 t}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Integrating this previous result yields:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e^{3 t}-\frac{5 e^{6 t}}{12} \\
 \frac{5 e^{2 t}}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This yields:

$$x_p(t) = \phi(t).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e^{3 t}-\frac{5 e^{6 t}}{12} \\
 \frac{5 e^{2 t}}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{5 e^{3 t}}{2} \\
 1+\frac{5 e^{3 t}}{6} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The final result is:

$$x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t)$$

This yields:

$$x(t) = c_1 e^t+\frac{5 e^{3 t}}{2} \\ y(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} c_1 \left(e^{4 t}-1\right) e^{-3 t}+c_2 e^{-3 t}+\dfrac{5 e^{3 t}}{6}+1$$

Comment: 1. This method requires a lot of computations which you skiped. 2. Even presented computations are with typos. 3. The way how the final solution is written indicates the use of some software like Mathematica.

Comment: And since the typos in your answer are not fixed, hence -1.

Answer (score -6):

You answer is incorrect.

How can you get a particular solution with $e^{2t}$ if your problem has $e^{3t}$?

A right way to do it is to represent
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5e^{3t}\\
3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
0
\end{bmatrix}e^{3t}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
3
\end{bmatrix}=f_1(t)+f_2(t)
$$
and first look for a solution of
$$
\dot x=Ax+f_1(t)
$$ in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}e^{3t},
$$
and then for a solution of 
$$
\dot x=Ax+f_2(t)
$$in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Both problems are elementary and can be solved for a few minutes.